# Оптимальный вариант ведения статистики

Tags: php

Как правильнее всего будет реализовать следующую задачу?

Существует 10+ файлов .php выполняющих разные функции и требуется вести статистику их активности, допустим какой файл сколько раз выполнился.. перед этим само собой получив данные из базы. Вроде задача простая, и с ходу можно придумать какой нибудь костыль, но я сильно задумался над правильностью ее реализации.

ps: Все скрипты выполняются прямым вызовом из главного index.php

Например такой вариант костыль или имеет право на жизнь, но все равно хотелось бы узнать как можно наиболее красиво сделать

```
class stat {

    protected $statistic = array();

    public function __construct () {
        $result = db_get_statistic();
        foreach ($result as $k => $v) {
            $this->statistic[$k] = $v;
        }
    }

    function refresh($key, $value) {
        $tmp = $this->statistic[$key] + $value;
        $this->statistic[$key] = $tmp;
    }

    function write() {
        db_write_statistic($this->statistic);
    }
}
```

Comment: Скрипты то через вэб выполняются? _server["script"] или как оно там

Comment: @teran они выполняются прямым вызовом из главного файла index.php

Comment: Вы не думаете, что это следует упомянуть в вопросе?

Comment: @teran честно, не подумал..

Comment: Вы можете записать в отдельный от остальных логов файл каждое обращение к функциям, по которым хотите собрать статистику.